# Fit image inside nested div

Tags: css

How can I fit this image inside the `div` with `inner` class using `CSS`? I can't change the `HTML`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

img {
  max-width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI2SB.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: max-width:100% ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, that seems to take care of width but not height.

Answer (score 1):

remove the p using `display:contents` and the task will be easy:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px black;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

p {
  display:contents;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI2SB.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use position:absolute

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px black;
  position:relative;
}

img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI2SB.jpg?s=328&g=1">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set `width` of your img to 100%

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: that seems to take care of width but not height

Comment: Problem with height maybe caused by p tag which have own margin. Set margin this to 0 ```p { margin: 0 }```